# The original Mesilas Yesharim

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, books-generally, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits

Mesilas Yesharim is a digest version of a previous work by the Ramchal.  This work is an ongoing conversation between a wise man and a pious man (Thank you chanoch for the correction).  I don't recall if it is called by the same name or not.

Does anyone know where I can get a copy of this sefer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Feldheim website](http://www.feldheim.com/mussar-growth-and-inspiration/classic-mussar-works/the-complete-mesillat-yesharim.html):

> Of the many works of Rabbi Moshe Hayyim Luzzatto, Mesillat Yesharim stands out as his magnum opus. Ever since it was first published in 1740 in Amsterdam, it has enjoyed great renown and was eventually adopted as a basic text for ethical study. Throughout the long history of its publication, Mesillat Yesharim fell prey to many printers' errors. A breakthrough in its restoration occurred with the remarkable discovery by Ofeq Institute of a manuscript of an earlier version in the form of a dialogue, in the author's own hand. With this discovery and the aid of the first edition, Mesillat Yesharim was restored to its original state.
>
> Over the last decade, Ofeq Institute has published both versions of Mesillat Yesharim, the Dialogue and the Thematic, in twin editions. For although the two versions share the same content, they each supplement elements missing in the other. Of pivotal importance are the added chapters at the beginning of the Dialogue Version. These shed light on the profound nature of the work as a whole. It has now become common practice to study the two versions together, for the Dialogue Version reveals the brilliance of Mesillat Yesharim for all who seek to deepen their understanding of it.

You can buy the book at the link above which includes both versions with translation.

Comment: Excellent find.  I wasn't expecting a state-of-the-art version.

Comment: Your link stoped working here is another one https://www.korenpub.com/ofeq_en_usd/the-complete-mesillat-yesharim-by-ramhal.html

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of Daat Tevunot which is translated by feldheim. http://www.feldheim.com/the-knowing-heart-da-ath-tevunoth.html

Comment: Da'at Tevunot covers the same subject matter as Derech Hashem, not Mesliat Yesharim.

Comment: @Chanoch no, Daat Tebunot is a dialogue between the mind and the soul, not Mesilat Yesharim. Messilat Yesharim is way to character perfection through service of God. Derech Hashem is an introduction and explanation of many concepts in Judaism.

Comment: @H'Gabriel, I see the dialogue comparison, but I was thinking of the one which jake linked to.

Comment: @H'Gabriel: Allow me to clarify. Daat Tevunot, Derech Hashem, and Ma'amar HaIkarim cover the same subject matter (generally speaking) but in different formats. Daat Tevunot is the dialog format, Derech Hashem is an expository format, and Ma'amar HaIkarim is a short summary essay. Mesliat Yesharim covers different subject matter in an expository format, and the Ofeq Institute's edition includes another version of Mesliat Yesharim in a dialog format. If you don't believe me, read them all yourself.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Daat Tevunot is a dialog between the intellect and the soul (not the body). The dialog format of Mesliat Yesharim is a dialog between a chacham and a chassid.